# macOS doesn't show the computer name correctly in Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

I have a 2011 MacBook Pro and it's name is set to **MacDavid**. I expect it to appear the same in Terminal.app, but it instead shows this:

```
w8-ricardo:~ davidpazo$
```

When i change the equip name, Terminal is indiferent. Any suggestion as to what could be causing this and how to resolve?

Comment: What do `echo $PS1` and `hostname` show?

Comment: this : \h:\W \u\$ you refer?

Comment: Yes! Sorry for duplicate, and than you is resolved :)) Delete the question?